# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular

private _user = new BehaviorSubject(null);

After get value from httpclient subscription, i'm trying to set value by this._user.next(value);

But getting error.
[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqMZQ.png)

```
auth.service.ts
export class AuthService{
    private _user = new BehaviorSubject<Auth>(null);
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    login(email:string,password:string){
        return this.http.post<{success:boolean,data:Auth}>(environment.app_url,{email,password})
        .pipe(tap(this.storeUser.bind(this)));
    }
    storeUser(data:{success:boolean,data:Auth}){
        let auth = data.data;
        console.log("store User",auth);
        this._user.next(auth)
    }
}
login.page.ts
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

    constructor( private auth:AuthService) {}
    logintheApp(){
        this.auth.login(this.email,this.password)
        .subscribe(
          data=>{
            // redirect to home page
          },err=>{
            //error
          }
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we may need more context. do you know when in the execution this is called (is it a result of a subscription, or an error after the .nex?)

Comment: Hi, could you post the code which leads up to this error? It will help us narrow down the issue and possibly provide a solution.

Comment: I have added my code, Please help me to fix it. thanks